# how to solve 'mat-list-option' is an Angular component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I have tried everything on the internet and nothing seems to fix my error.

this is my NgModule :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './MainLayout/main-layout/main-layout.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ContainersPageComponent } from './Containers/containers-page/containers-page.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MarinServiceService } from './services/marin-service.service';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainLayoutComponent,
    ContainersPageComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,

  ],
  providers: [MarinServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the exact Error im getting :

```
)
: 'mat-selection-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-selection-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-selection-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

  <!--Check Box Search-->
  [ERROR ->]<mat-selection-list >
    <mat-list-option >
```

I have tried re-Importing and it didn't work.
I have tried importing everything Mat related.

I really don't know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: I think you mean _'mat-list-option' is **not** an Angular component?_ Maybe include a stack trace of the error, and the template in which you implemented it?

Comment: what's the exact error you are getting actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import **`MatListModule`**

```
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
```

Add it under imports array of the **`app.module.ts`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Mat List Module in the concerned module.

`import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';`

More information: https://material.angular.io/components/list/api